# How to work with audio files?

Tags: python, audio

A digital image consists of multiple pixels, each of them has some values which indicate the intensity of the corresponding colors. If I want to work with images I can simply read or change pixels. For scientific purposes there is for example the [PPM-Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format), which encodes each pixel one by one in readable ASCII format.

Is there a similar way to read or modify audio files? How is audio edited? What are the building blocks, the smallest parts, the “pixels” of audio recordings? Is there an ASCII sound file format?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Python, but this was meant as a general question.

Comment: You should tag it appropriately (you could also mention this is a general question and not aimed at this language only).  Few people cover the audio tag and do not even know what to use in order to help, for this reason it is unlikely you will get any answers.  Good tagging (without spamming) will increase your chances of getting answers greatly.

Comment: This question is much too broad and off-topic for SO. See [what is on topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation#Modulation contains a pretty accessible introduction.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably completely off topic, but here you are...

An audio file consists of samples representing air movement at a certain point of time. In case of CD quality, that is 44100 samples per second, 16 bits each.

I don't think visualising that as ASCII would be very useful. You would need at least 3 characters per sample, which is 132300 characters per second of sound, or 39690000 (that is 40 millions) characters for a 5-minute song.

Comment: "representing air movement at a certain point of time" - No! It represents the percentage of max. output voltage or current at a certain time. This has nothing to do with air movement. And please don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: @Olaf First: the output voltage definitely has something to do with air movement. Otherwise it would not be an audio file, but a voltmeter readout data file. Secondly, I am not 100% sure this is off topic. Understanding file formats is part of programming and this is a WAV format topic. It is definitely not a Python question though.

Comment: There is no need for any air movement to listen to audio. One could stimulate the nerves directly like in cochlea implants. Or - more common - using bone-stimulation. When processing, there is no air involved either (unless your computer works with pneumatics). And even if you use air as medium to send the audio to the ear, the data does not encode the air movement, but (simplified) the position of a membrane. The air movement is the result of the alternating positions, not directly encoded by the dataword. So yes, it is a "voltage-ratio" encoding. And there was no mention of `WAV` format.

Comment: @Olaf Hahaha that would mean that a bitmap's values have nothing to do with light intensities of RGB colours, but only represent the level of electrical impulses in the optical nerve! That is wrong. Likewise, audio files represent sound and sound is by definition a mechanical wave. Not necessarily in air, but usually when we talk about sound we imply vibrations in air. Electricity is definitely not essential for sound, or for computers in fact or for anything concerning audio files.

Comment: "An audio file **consists of samples representing air movement at a certain point of time**" - I did not comment about audio files, but your definition of what a single sample means. Anyway, there is little use in discussing with ignorance and you ignored the actual point about [not answering OT questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions). Feel free to have the final laugh,  Pennywise.

Comment: @Olaf I actually gave an answer to your comment about answering an off topic question: I am not sure it is off topic. The meta link you gave gives absolutely no right to decide for me what I am or am not allowed to do. Please refrain from appointing yourself to the position of a SO censor.